# Can't find "Python.h" file while installing Watchman

Tags: python, linux, watchman

I use Linux Mint 17 'Quiana' and I want to install Watchman to use later Ember.js. Here were my steps:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
```

then

```
$ cd watchman
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure.sh
```

and, when I ran `make` to compile files, it returned the following error:

```
pywatchman/bser.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: no such file or directory
#include <Python.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
make[1]: *** [py-build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving the directory `/home/alex/watchman'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to run

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

but it appears to be already in my system. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried installing `libpython3-dev`, too?

Comment: Usually its the python-dev libs missing.
Are you sure the configure uses the python 3 instead of python 2? Because if thats the case you should install `python-dev` instead of `python3-dev`.
@NilsWerner python3-dev should install `libpython3-dev` as dependency.

Comment: Well if it does my guess would also be a Python 2/3 configuration problem.

Comment: You need python-dev not python3-dev. Watchman uses python2

Comment: @Tomax, so you were right, that was the problem - I had to install python 2 `dev`, now it works. thanks!

Comment: Thanks @AlexNikolaev94, give it the answer status so it can help others with same or similar problems to yours.

Comment: @Tomax sure, but how can I do that?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 After reading the meta, I guess I shall put the comment as answer and you acknowledge it.. I'm kinda new in here... :)

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 `sudo apt-get install python-dev` solved my problem. Try it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Usually its the `python-dev` libs missing. Are you sure the configure uses the python 3 instead of python 2? Because if thats the case you should install `python-dev` instead of `python3-dev`.

Comment: On Fedora 24 you need `sudo dnf install python-devel`.

Comment: `sudo yum install python-devel` for CENTOS

Answer (score 7):

Same problem if you build watchman under rasbian/raspberry. Install "python-dev".

--

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman
./autogen.sh
./configure
make

sudo make install
```

Answer (score 7):

i also did

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

it was still giving me the error then i ran this command

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

after that.

```
make 
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

on Fedora 32 run:  `sudo dnf install python-devel`